# Unable to show the Default Values in the TextField

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am having an issue in defaultValues. I am getting data from **GET API** and want to show the default values in the field which i got from the backend.
All the values are present in **initialFieldValuesCopy** but i'm unable to show them in my text fields. if a user want to change data it should be changeable means user will be able to make alteration in the data which is from the backend
i'm using **PUT API** like if the user changes the data in field it works and data is stored at backend

The code is given below

```
    interface UserData {
  id: string;
  email: string;
  fullName: string;
  phone: string;
  website: string;
  company: string;
  country: string;
  language: string;
  timeZone: string;
  currency: string;
  description: string;
  photoURL: string;
  // Add other fields with their types here
}

const AvatarViewWrapper = styled('div')(({ theme }) => {
  return {
    position: 'relative',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    '& .edit-icon': {
      position: 'absolute',
      bottom: 0,
      right: 0,
      zIndex: 1,
      border: `solid 2px ${theme.palette.background.paper}`,
      backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.primary.main, 0.7),
      color: theme.palette.primary.contrastText,
      borderRadius: '50%',
      width: 26,
      height: 26,
      display: 'none',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      transition: 'all 0.4s ease',
      cursor: 'pointer',
      '& .MuiSvgIcon-root': {
        fontSize: 16,
      },
    },
    '&.dropzone': {
      outline: 0,
      '&:hover .edit-icon, &:focus .edit-icon': {
        display: 'flex',
      },
    },
  };
});

const PersonalInfo = () => {
  const { user } = useAuthUser();
  const { getRootProps, getInputProps } = useDropzone({
    accept: {
      'image/png': ['.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg'],
    },
    onDrop: (acceptedFiles) => {
      setImageFile(acceptedFiles[0]);
    },
  });

  const [imageFile, setImageFile] = useState<File | null>(null);
  const [initialFieldValues, setInitialFieldValues] = useState<UserData>({
    id: '',
    email: '',
    fullName: '',
    phone: '',
    website: '',
    company: '',
    country: '',
    language: '',
    timeZone: '',
    currency: '',
    description: '',
    photoURL: '/assets/images/placeholder.jpg',
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch user details from the GET service
    const fetchUserData = async () => {
      try {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        const response = await axios.get(
          'https://admin.accountsdash.com/api/User/account',
          {
            headers: {
              accept: '*/*',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
          }
        );

        const userResponse = response.data;
        console.log(userResponse);

        // Verify that userResponse is not empty and contains the expected data
        if (userResponse) {
          // Set the initial field values with the data from the API
          setInitialFieldValues({
            id: userResponse.id,
            email: userResponse.email,
            fullName: userResponse.fullName,
            phone: userResponse.phoneNumber,
            website: userResponse.webSite,
            company: userResponse.company,
            country: userResponse.country,
            language: userResponse.language,
            timeZone: userResponse.timeZone,
            currency: userResponse.currency,
            description: userResponse.description,
            photoURL: userResponse.photoURL || '/assets/images/placeholder.jpg',
          });
        } else {
          console.error('Received empty or unexpected data from the API.');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching user data:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchUserData();
  }, []);

  const initialFieldValuesCopy = { ...initialFieldValues };
  console.log('Initial Field Values:', initialFieldValues);

  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        position: 'relative',
        maxWidth: 550,
      }}
    >
      <Formik
        initialValues={initialFieldValues}
        validateOnChange={false}
        validateOnBlur={true}
        onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
          handleFormSubmit(values, imageFile, setSubmitting);
        }}
      >
        {({ values, setFieldValue, isSubmitting }) => (
          <Form>
            <AvatarBox>
              <AvatarViewWrapper {...getRootProps({ className: 'dropzone' })}>
                <input {...getInputProps()} />
                <label htmlFor="icon-button-file">
                  <AvatarStyle
                    src={initialFieldValues.photoURL || values.photoURL}
                  />
                  <Box className="edit-icon">
                    <EditIcon />
                  </Box>
                </label>
              </AvatarViewWrapper>
              <FullNameBox>
                <Typography
                  sx={{
                    fontWeight: Fonts.MEDIUM,
                  }}
                >
                  {initialFieldValues.fullName}
                </Typography>
                <Typography
                  sx={{
                    color: (theme) => theme.palette.text.secondary,
                  }}
                >
                  {initialFieldValues.email}
                </Typography>
              </FullNameBox>
            </AvatarBox>
            <Grid container spacing={2} sx={{ mb: 4 }} alignItems={'center'}>
              <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
                <TextField
                  fullWidth
                  name="fullName"
                  label="Full Name"
                  defaultValue={initialFieldValues.fullName}
                  onChange={(e) => setFieldValue('fullName', e.target.value)}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
                <TextField
                  fullWidth
                  name="email"
                  label="Email"
                  defaultValue={initialFieldValuesCopy.email}
                  disabled
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
                <TextField
                  fullWidth
                  name="phone"
                  label="Phone"
                  defaultValue={initialFieldValues.phone}
                  onChange={(e) => setFieldValue('phone', e.target.value)}
                />
              </Grid>
              {*/ Remaining Field */}
              <Button type="submit" name="submitButton">
              Submit
              </Button>
            </Form>
           )}
         </Formik>
        </Box>
       );
      };
```

The PUT API:

```
const handleFormSubmit = (
  data: UserData,
  imageFile: File | null,
  setSubmitting: (isSubmitting: boolean) => void
) => {
  setSubmitting(true);

  const formData = new FormData();
  if (imageFile) {
    formData.append('ProfileImage', imageFile);
  }
  formData.append('Id', '5eb37003-6923-4939-5241-08dbd3b53cb0');
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-debugger
  debugger;
  formData.append('Username', 'sadia.software@gmail.com');
  formData.append('Email', 'sadia.software@gmail.com');
  formData.append('PhoneNumber', data.phone);
  // formData.append('BirthDay', data.dob.toISOString());
  formData.append('BirthDay', '2023-10-02T19:00:00');
  formData.append('Website', data.website);
  // formData.append('Company', data.company);
  // formData.append('Country', data.country);
  formData.append('FullName', data.fullName);
  formData.append('Language', data.language);
  formData.append('TimeZone', data.timeZone);
  formData.append('Currency', data.currency);
  // formData.append('Description', data.description);

  // Append other form fields to formData
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-debugger
  debugger;

  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  axios
    .put('https://admin.accountsdash.com/api/User/account', formData, {
      headers: {
        accept: '*/*',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log('User data updated:', response.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      if (error.response) {
        console.error('Error updating user data:', error.response.data);
      } else {
        console.error('Network error:', error.message);
      }
    })
    .finally(() => {
      setSubmitting(false);
    });
};
```

Any Help will be Appreciated.
Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

As per your use case, you need to reinitialize the initial values of the form. There is a prop called `enableReinitialize` which defaults to `false`, set it to `true` to fix your issue. Here is the [documentation](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#enablereinitialize-boolean).

Comment: can you please guide how to do so? i have tried a lot of solutions

Comment: I think adding the prop should fix as per your code.

Answer (score 0):

The `initialValues` are only set during the first render in which no data is present yet.

instead of setting the values in your useEffect with `setInitialFieldValues` you can try and use the `resetForm` with the values gained from the API according [to the documentation](https://formik.org/docs/migrating-v2#resetform)

Comment: can you please guide how can i do so.